# How to set nested css classes into CssResources

Tags: css, gwt

for example i have this html div structure

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">
      <div class="child21"></div>
      <div class="child22"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and these r the corresponding classes

```
.parent{ /*stuff*/}
.parent .child1{/*stuff*/}
.parent .child1 .child21{/*stuff*/}
.parent .child1 .child22{/*stuff*/}
```

So how to set the class names in the CssResource for these nested divs. I tried different combinations but no one works. I will show some of these combinations which dont work.

```
public interface CssStuff extends CssResource{
      public String parent();  // works

      Classname("parent child1")
      public String child1();   // dont work

      Classname("parent .child1 .child21")
      public String child21();   // dont work

      Classname("parent.child1.child22")
      public String child22();   // dont work
 }
```

I get following error messages:

> Replacing CSS class names
>     The following obfuscated style classes were missing from the CSS file:
>     parent .child1: Fix by adding .parent .child1{}

and so on.

I mean the classes are existing in the CSS file.
So whats wrong and how to set these classes in the CssResource?

Answer (score 2):

Nested classnames are just classnames, so just change your code to:

```
public interface CssStuff extends CssResource{
  public String parent();
  public String child1();
  public String child21();
  public String child22();
}
```

And you will get the obfuscated named of those classes, to use in your widgets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to use GWT, but I do know that "parent" in every example is not referred to as a class, as it is missing a "."

To target a css selector child it would be

```
.parent .child1
.parent .child1 .child21
```

If you have multiple classes on a DOM element such as

```
<div class="parent child1">
```

The resulting selector would be

```
.parent.child1
```

You have this correct in your css example, but as I stated before I'm not familiar with GWT.